# Get a new instance of a durandal viewmodel with every system.acquire

Tags: javascript, requirejs, durandal

I'm using the hottowel template and I'm trying to load views dynamically on to a dashboard type view.

The views should also be able to be viewed individually.

So lets say i have a graph view. I want to be able to navigate to it like this :"mysite.com/#/graph/1".

I should also be able to compose the view through ko bindings into the dashboard view.

What I'm doing right now is to on the activate method of the dashboard load a users saved dashboard views. Like this:

### dashboard activate

```
function activate() {

        return datacontext.getUserDashboardConfigurations(userId)
        .then(function (data) {

            _.each(data.elements(), function (view) {
                system.acquire("viewmodels/" + view.viewType()).then(function (model) {
                    var newModel =  model.create(); //factory method
                    newModel.__moduleId__ = model.__moduleId__;
                    newModel.viewSettingsId(view.SettingsId());
                    views.push(newModel);
                });
            });

            vm.showLoad(false);
        });
    }
```

I probably haven't understood how durandal and/or require correctly. But the model returned by the acquire method is the same for every view of the same type. 3 graph views composed to the dashboard all gets the same instance of the graph model. So what I did was to create a sort of factory method for the model.

### Graph model

```
define( function(logger, dataContext) {

    function model() {
        var viewSettingsId= ko.observable(0);      

        function activate() {
        //omitted
        }

        function viewAttached(view) {
            //omitted
        }

        return {
            activate: activate,         
            title: 'Graph View',
            viewSettingsId: viewSettingsId
        };
    }

    return {
        create: function() {
            return new model();
        }
    };
});
```

### ko binding

```
    <div id="columns" data-bind=" foreach: views">
            <div  data-bind="compose: { model: $data, activate: true, alwaysAttachView: true, preserveContext: false } "></div>
    </div>
```

### router overridden

```
  router.getActivatableInstance = function(routeInfo, params, module) {
        if (typeof module == 'function') {
            return new module();
        } else {
            if (module.create && typeof module.create == 'function') {
                var newModule = module.create();
                newModule.__moduleId__ = module.__moduleId__;

                return newModule;
            }
            return module;
        }
    };
```

This sort of solves the problem for the dashboard. Navigation also work. But I feel that there must be a better solution. Maybe durandal widgets? But I want to have them as normal views and "widgets" on the dashboard. How can I solve this in a cleaner way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. I found the samples, duh. I have overlooked that link in the documentation.

The master detail sample made it clear. Changed viewmodel to use the prototype pattern in the example. Then use the viewmodel.activateItem after system.acquire.

Then compose the views like the example. Works and feels cleaner!

### dashboard activate

```
function activate() {
        return datacontext.getUserDashboardConfigurations(userId)
        .then(function (data) {

            currentDashboardconfiguration = data;

            _.each(data.elements(), function (view) {


                system.acquire("viewmodels/" + view.viewType()).then(function (model) {

                    var newModel = new model();

                    viewModel.activator().activateItem(newModel, { id: view.viewSettingsId() }).then(function (suc) {
                        views.push(newModel);
                    });
                });
            });

            vm.showLoad(false);
        });
}
```

### graph model

```
define( function(logger, dataContext) {


    var ctor = function()
    {
        this.viewSettingsId = ko.observable(0); 
        this.title: 'Graph View',  
    }

    ctor.prototype.activate = function() {
        //omitted
     }

    ctor.prototype.viewAttached = function(view) {
       //omitted
    }

    return ctor;
});
```

### ko binding

```
<div id="columns" data-bind=" foreach: views">
    <div class="widget column" data-bind="compose: $data"></div>
</div>
```